# How to browse to a file server and add a printer via command line

Tags: command-line

I have a file server that holds all of the printers my company uses. Lets call this \printers. I can add the printers by browsing to this location and double clicking on the printer. It will install the correct driver and I am good to go. I want to be able to do this via command line so that I can add printers to peoples computers without having to log remote into their computers.

I know that I can add printers via the IP address that they use. I was just thinking that if I could enter in a command to browse to the \printers location and run the printer name and add the printer.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Could you specify on which operating system the printer should be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using group policy, you can do it with that. That is probably the perfered method.

But you asked for command line. Try this out:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n "\\servername\printername
```

Comment: rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n "\\servername\printername worked. Thanks Nixphoe

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a domain?  You should be doing this via group policy.

If not, then you can do this using the using the Windows Scripting host [WshNetwork.AddPrinterConnection method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsdca3c.aspx) from vbscript or powershell.  Using this through powershell should be as simple as something like this.  You may get a UAC prompt.

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\ps-01\prn-01")
```

Versions of windows newer than (8/2012) also have the powershell [Add-Printer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918353.aspx).

Comment: Oh, powershell! me gusta